# 404 error although route exists in laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

I have routes like this: `Route::resource('admin/post', 'Admin\PostsController');`
Route for edit post exists but I get `404` error. I list all routes `php artisan r:l` and it shows me the `post.edit` but it doesn't show me edit page.

```
in web.php
  Route::resource('admin/post', 'Admin\PostsController');
in Admin\PostsController
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('backend.posts.edit', compact('post'));
}
```

in index.php

```
<a href="{{route('post.edit', $post->id)}}" class="btn btn-sx btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
```

[image]

this is the error of edit page
[image]